# update the user table from request table using laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to update the user table from request table using laravel 5
Please suggest how it can be done with ease. I have two tables data and want to update user table based on request table data where request table has foreign sm_id and user table has primary id please suggest

Thanks in advance

Request data:

```
Array (

 [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [sm_id] => 1 [field_name] => first_name [value] => G2 [created_at] => 2017-02-27 14:17:35 [updated_at] => 2017-02-24 11:05:03 [deleted_at] => )

 [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [sm_id] => 4 [field_name] => phone [value] => 123467890 [created_at] => 2017-02-27 16:55:48 [updated_at] => 2017-02-27 11:02:27 [deleted_at] => )

 [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [sm_id] => 4 [field_name] => first_name [value] => John [created_at] => 2017-02-27 16:55:48 [updated_at] => 2017-02-27 11:02:27 [deleted_at] => )

 [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [sm_id] => 4 [field_name] => last_name [value] => Hunny [created_at] => 2017-02-27 16:55:48 [updated_at] => 2017-02-27 11:02:27 [deleted_at] => ) )

User Data:

Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [social_id] => 
    [role_id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [first_name] => max
    [last_name] => rony
    [gender] => male
    [dob] => 02-02-2017
    [language] => english
    [location] => USA
    [address] => ABCD
    [email] => max.jrny@jioc.com
    [phone] => 7894561230
    [id_proof] => 
    [id_proof_path] => 
    [remember_token] => 
    [provider] => website
    [biography] => Here is about 
    [approve] => 1
    [created_at] => 2017-02-22 12:16:56
    [updated_at] => 2017-02-22 12:16:56
    [deleted_at] => 
)


Expected result in user table

Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [social_id] => 
    [role_id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [first_name] => john
    [last_name] => Hunny
    [gender] => male
    [dob] => 02-02-2017
    [language] => english
    [location] => USA
    [address] => ABCD
    [email] => max.jrny@jioc.com
    [phone] => 123467890
    [id_proof] => 
    [id_proof_path] => 
    [remember_token] => 
    [provider] => website
    [biography] => Here is about 
    [approve] => 1
    [created_at] => 2017-02-22 12:16:56
    [updated_at] => 2017-02-22 12:16:56
    [deleted_at] => 
)


Here is my code

 public function verifyInformation($id){

      if($id){

        $getRequest = request::all()->toArray();

        $user = User::where('id', $id)->first()->toArray();

        foreach($getRequest as $row=>$value){
            foreach($value as $rowKey => $result){
                   $array_key = array_keys($user);

                    $arrayDiff = array_diff($value, $user);
                    $find = $arrayDiff['field_name'];  


                    if(in_array($find, $array_key)){
                        foreach($array_key as $k => $v){

                          if($v == $find){
                            $fieldKey = $v;
                            $fieldValue =  $arrayDiff['value'];

                            if($fieldValue){

                              $user = new User;  
                              $user->$fieldKey = $fieldValue;
                              $user->save();

                              return redirect()->back()->with("status", "Well done!! profile updated successfully");
                            }

                          }

                        }
                    }       
            }
        }


      }
    }
```

**Note:** only phone, first_name and last_name updated in expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will provide an updated array to save and indicate if any values have changed.  It is just four declarations to set things up, followed by a foreach loop containing a condition statement which commands the push of data into the array.  Modify my snippet to suit your purpose.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c11cefb678c451b67d36c9b8444fe9d83e406e97)

```
$request_data=array(
    0=>array(
        "id" => 1,
        "sm_id" => 1,
        "field_name" => "first_name",
        "value" => "G2",
        "created_at" => "2017-02-27 14:17:35",
        "updated_at" => "2017-02-24 11:05:03",
        "deleted_at" => ""),
    1=>array(
        "id" => 2,
        "sm_id" => 4,
        "field_name" => "phone",
        "value" => 123467890,
        "created_at" => "2017-02-27 16:55:48",
        "updated_at" => "2017-02-27 11:02:27",
        "deleted_at" => ""
    ),
    2=>array(
        "id" => 3,
        "sm_id" => 4,
        "field_name" => "first_name",
        "value" => "John",
        "created_at" => "2017-02-27 16:55:48",
        "updated_at" => "2017-02-27 11:02:27",
        "deleted_at" => ""
    ),
    3=>array(
        "id" => 4,
        "sm_id" => 4,
        "field_name" => "last_name",
        "value" => "Hunny",
        "created_at" => "2017-02-27 16:55:48",
        "updated_at" => "2017-02-27 11:02:27",
        "deleted_at" => ""
    )
);

$user_data=array(
    "id" => 4,
    "social_id" => "",
    "role_id" => 0,
    "name" => "",
    "first_name" => "max",
    "last_name" => "rony",
    "gender" => "male",
    "dob" => "02-02-2017",
    "language" => "english",
    "location" => "USA",
    "address" => "ABCD",
    "email" => "max.jrny@jioc.com",
    "phone" => "7894561230",
    "id_proof" => "",
    "id_proof_path" => "",
    "remember_token" => "",
    "provider" => "website",
    "biography" => "Here is about",
    "approve" => 1,
    "created_at" => "2017-02-22 12:16:56",
    "updated_at" => "2017-02-22 12:16:56",
    "deleted_at" => ""
);

$new_data=$user_data;
$user_id=$user_data["id"];  // declare target id
$request_ids=array_column($request_data,"sm_id");  // read sm_id column to array
$request_indexes=array_keys($request_ids,$user_id);  // declare matching indexes

// loop an subarrays that contain the appropriate sm_id
foreach(array_intersect_key($request_data,array_flip($request_indexes)) as $row){
    // if row contains one of the chosen values, overwrite the original data
    if(in_array($row["field_name"],array("phone","first_name","last_name"))){
        $new_data[$row["field_name"]]=$row["value"];
    }
}

if($user_data!=$new_data){
    echo "Changes to save";
}else{
    echo "No changes to save";
}
echo "<pre>";
var_export($new_data);
echo "</pre>";
```

This is the output:

```
Changes to save
array (
  'id' => 4,
  'social_id' => '',
  'role_id' => 0,
  'name' => '',
  'first_name' => 'John',
  'last_name' => 'Hunny',
  'gender' => 'male',
  'dob' => '02-02-2017',
  'language' => 'english',
  'location' => 'USA',
  'address' => 'ABCD',
  'email' => 'max.jrny@jioc.com',
  'phone' => 123467890,
  'id_proof' => '',
  'id_proof_path' => '',
  'remember_token' => '',
  'provider' => 'website',
  'biography' => 'Here is about',
  'approve' => 1,
  'created_at' => '2017-02-22 12:16:56',
  'updated_at' => '2017-02-22 12:16:56',
  'deleted_at' => '',
)
```